# not empty string have "false" value

Tags: javascript, string

In my API (node/express server) i am checking received cookies and getting false result of not empty string. `console.log(req.headers.cookie)` returns string value `"key=value..."`, but `console.log(req.headers.cookie == true)` returns `'false'` and i just cant pass through this check `if(req.headers.cookie) {//do something..}`. I dont understand this logic, only empty string "" should return 'false' value or nor?

---

Answer (score 1):

`"key=value..."` no equal to `true` but it has truthy value.
If statement check if the value is truthy, not if the value is true.

In javascript there are 6 falsy values:

1. false
2. 0 (zero)
3. '' (empty string)
4. null
5. undefined
6. NaN

All other values are truthy.

Comment: Was misunderstanding about comparison not empty string and boolean true. Looks like after restarting node and react servers all works for first request and then again breaks. Thanks.